# WordPress Contact form 7 Forbidden error

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

When i have click on save button at that time this error message is display.

Forbidden
You don’t have permission to access /wp-admin/admin.php on this server.

Can you tell me what is a problem ?

Comment: you are not logged in as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as an administrator? If so, you might check the the admin folder has the right permissions. Here is a link to the WordPress Codex - https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions. You can use an FTP client to check the permissions of the wp-admin folder if it is on a remote server.

Comment: Yes, I am login as admin, but i dont't know way it was happening

Comment: Is this your local machine or is it a web hosting server? If it is your local machine you should check the permissions of the folder you installed it in.

Comment: No website is under Live server.